# Java: I want to get an Integer output in double datatype

Tags: java, double, decimal

```
class simple {
    public static void main() {
        double n, m;
        Scanner ip = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = ip.nextDouble();
        m = ip.nextDouble();
        m = n * m;
        System.out.println("Value in " + m);
    }
}
```

In the above code.. 
   My output should only use decimal poinf if my input is using decimal point, rest of the time it should print like an integer.

Ex : `INPUT : 2 , 3`  --> `OUTPUT : Value is 6`

`INPUT : 2.1, 1` --> `OUTPUT : Value is 2.1`

So my question is....  How can i print my number (with decimal point, without decimal point) according to my input?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: `if ((m - (int) m) == 0)` is `true` only if the number is `x.0`.

Comment: I am a novice in java. Please don't discourage me by down voting.

Comment: it's the opposite. I'm encouraging you by the downvote. Try to learn from it and improve your question. You should be clearer; Ask a question, don't only post a code.

Comment: How can i print my number (with decimal point, without decimal point) according to my input? @maroun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NumberFormat`; the #-sign mean that decimals are only shown if they're non-zero.

```
System.out.println("Value in " + new DecimalFormat("0.########").format(m));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    double n1,n2,n3,checkdecimal;
    n3=n1*n2;
    checkdecimal = n3 - Math.floor(n3);
    if(checkdecimal == 0)
    screen.setText(new DecimalFormat("0.#").format(this.Answer) + ""); // It will print without decimal point
    else
    screen.setText(this.Answer +""); // It will print with decimal point
```

Finally i found the solution myself ...

Answer (score -4):

Use Math.round() (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)) to round your output!

Comment: The OP doesn't want to round if the input values are non-integers.

Comment: Well so first he just needs to check for that, and then round!